# Android Jetpack DataStore Fatal Exception: java.io.IOException

Tags: android, kotlin

Im using datastore in one of my android library and I get crashes from google vitals that I cant reproduce and should not be possible...

I create my datastore as per guide:

```
val Context.baseDataStore by preferencesDataStore(
name = "my_pref")
```

This is ofcourse on the top level and outside of any class, so by default it should always be a single instance, and I access the data store by using the context.baseDataStore in my app,but then I get this from crashlytics:

Fatal Exception: java.io.IOException
Unable to rename /data/user/0/com.myapp/files/datastore/my_pref.preferences_pb.tmp.This likely means that there are multiple instances of DataStore for this file. Ensure that you are only creating a single instance of datastore for this file.

Can anything be done about it?

Additional Info: It looks like it happens once on upgrade since crashlytics says its crashing in the first second. Also it looks like it is happening only once per upgrade since the occurrences are dropping to 0 after a new version release

Comment: How many times do you make an instance with this name? maybe you have made it in just one place but it is called several times

Comment: There should be only 1 instance of it since im creating it as per guide:                                           val Context.baseDataStore by preferencesDataStore(
    name = DATASTORE_NAME
)
and then accessing it from the context itself

Comment: @user924941 it's not really that clear from the documentation. I'm looking at java docs for `preferencesDataStore` and it states "This should only be called once in a file (at the top level), and all usages of the DataStore should use a reference the same Instance.". That to me suggests that it's your responsibility to make sure the same instance is being used

Comment: It seems that by any chance your code is creating multiple instance or writing data from multiple places simultaneously while upgrade. As stated in issue tracker of preferencesDataStore, renaming my_pref.preferences_pb.tmp will occur during data writing. May be one is trying to write while another one already renamed the file to my_pref.preferences_pb. Can you double check the instance calling?